# Print content of div using print style sheet

Tags: html, css

I need to print content of a div using print style sheet.My div has big ordered list (200+ lines).
Issue : 
only print the content of div which is fitted with first page.rest of the content is not showing in print.

```
@media print
{
    body *
    {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #printcontent, #printcontent *
    {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    #printcontent
    {
        background-color: white;
        border: 0px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px !important;
        left: 0px !important;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 18px;
        display: inline; 
        overflow: visible !important;
    }

    *
    {
        overflow: visible !important;
    }
    #nonPrintableTable
    {
        display: none;
    }
    #nonPrintableTable div
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Note:
I changed doc type in order to fix positioning issue on IE.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Why `display: inline;` for `#printcontent`, I wonder.

Comment: i changed display:block to display:inline as suggested by forum.nothing was happened.

Comment: is this on a publicly accessible URL? If not can you code it up into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please.